# Placing a textblock in a certain grid column

Tags: silverlight, textblock

I populate a textblock with data from Service and I bind the data to Listbox and then display it in textblocks, so far so good. My problem is that I want each textblock content to be placed in certain space in certain column, but this doesn't seem to work as my text is just put in each line and is not alligned as it should be.
here is my code:

```
<Grid x:Name="BranchesGrid" Margin="12,0,-12,6" Grid.Row="2" Height="542" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ListBox Height="530" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,6,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="0" Padding="55,10,5,10" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="1" Padding="110,10,5,10" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding City}" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="2" Padding="70,10,5,10" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
```

Where seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Grid x:Name="BranchesGrid" Margin="12,0,-12,6" Grid.Row="2" Height="542" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <ListBox Height="530" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,6,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="0" Padding="55,10,5,10" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="1" Padding="110,10,5,10" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding City}" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="2" Padding="70,10,5,10" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try it later when I'm home and I'll tell you if it works :)

Comment: sweet deal, man. Worked just as I wanted. Thank you so much :)